# What is matshow() of matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm learning refer to matplotlib in Python, so I have found some references about it, but I don't understand completely. What does it really do? When do we use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot.matshow()` This is mostly used to visualize the 2D matrix. It will show same color for the same number inside matrix.

Lets take an example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [[0,0,1], [3,4,5]]

plt.matshow(a)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. I got it! It's really simple when you define it.